# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0-

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
String productName = request.getParameter("productName");
int productPrice = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productPrice"));

String query = " INSERT INTO PRODUCTS values(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("query");
int i = 1;

pst.setInt(1, i);
pst.setString(2, productName);
pst.setInt(3, productPrice);
i++;
pst.executeUpdate(query);
con.close();
```

Comment: change `pst.executeUpdate(query);` to `pst.executeUpdate();`

Comment: can you share correct code and problem you are facing ?

Comment: Guys I didn't get any proper answer instack overflow to solve this error. I need to get rid of this error. need help

Comment: Eran that doesn't help

Comment: @Eran `con.prepareStatement("query");` looks wrong as well, shouldn't that be `con.prepareStatement(query);`?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I didn't notice that one.

Comment: @Eran and Oh God Spiders I have changed those..I agree those were errors.. I have corrected..thanks.. But still getting the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("query");
```

to

```
PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
```

Notice that you need to pass actual `query` variable not a "query" string

and as Mark noted below:
In addition `pst.executeUpdate(query)` needs to be changed to `pst.executeUpdate()`.

Comment: In addition `pst.executeUpdate(query)` needs to be changed to `pst.executeUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify colum names you want to insert

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
     preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
```